# How can I center an element relative to its parent?

Tags: css

I have the following container:

```
#container {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

It was generated using nifty:layout Rails generator. How would I center something inside of this container, and not the entire page?

EDIT:
Sorry for not providing further info :). This is what I'm trying to center:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <% if current_user %>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign out",destroy_user_session_path %><span>|</span></li>
            <li><%= link_to "New snippet",new_snippet_path %><span>|</span></li>
        <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Login",new_user_session_path %><span>|</span></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Register",new_user_registration_path %><span>|</span></li>
        <% end %>
        <li><%= link_to "Snippets",snippets_path %><span>|</span></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Chat",messages_path %></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS I have for it so far:

```
#nav {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#nav li {
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: What kind of an element are you trying to center? Can you show some HTML?

Comment: Could you show the **HTML**, instead of the Ruby? View source, perhaps?

Comment: It's just a div, with a ul, and a bunch of li's. It's a navigation menu.

Answer (score 6):

If you're trying to center the `display: inline` list elements, giving the container

```
text-align: center
```

will work.

If it's about block elements, @slhck's and @anirudh's answers are the solution.

Comment: But the text-align:center is centering to the page. I had tried that too.

Comment: @Geo: From what I can see, `text-align: center` should be working. Can you add your (relevant) complete HTML (obtained from View Source, not the Ruby version), and CSS to a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Yes, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/zW2vW/1/ . I also added comments where the application.css begins and where the style.css begins.

Comment: @Geo the snippet looks fine to me. It centers the navigation elements relative to the page, but also relative to the container element

Answer (score 3):

I guess the following should do. Assign a fixed width, and then

```
#inside-container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50px;
}
```

You can specify top and bottom margins, but the `auto` value for left and right will make the element centered.

*Update: Didn't see your code before. See @Pekka's answer for `inline` elements.*

Answer (score 1):

Make the div with `id="container"`, have a `class="container"` class and do

```
.container #innerElement {
 position: relative;      
 width: <set width here>;
 margin: auto;
 }
```