# How to centralize second element inline relative to parent?

Tags: css, alignment

I'm trying make a layout for mobile application.

How do I centralize the title label relative to parent?

Here's my HTML:

```
  <div id="title">
    <i class="fa fa-th-large" id="menuButton"></i>
    <small class="title">PROFILE</small>
  </div>
```

[See in jsBIN](http://jsbin.com/lezelugipa/edit?html,css,output)

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I center an element relative to it's parent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318608/how-can-i-center-an-element-relative-to-its-parent)

Comment: What do you mean by centralize? And there's no label element here (as in label as html element). What is the parent? Is it the body element or the #title div? Cause you also have a .title div and it is confusing. Do what on what relative to what?

Comment: I need centralize "Profile" only

Answer (score 0):

try to add margin to title, like this:

```
#title{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do u mean you want to centralize the text inside  ? If so, try this code:

```
#title {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Centering the Profile only:

HTML:

```
   <div id="title">
     <div id="icon">
       <i class="fa fa-th-large" id="menuButton"></i>
     </div>
     <div id="text">
       <small class="title">PROFILE</small>
      </div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
#title {
  background: #13A3B5;
  padding: 10px 5%;
  font-size: 2em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#icon {
  float: left;
  width: 5%;
}

#text {
  float: left;
  width: 95%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: How to can I centralize "Profile" only, and maintain icon in left align?

Comment: I will try make two seperate divs and float them. See the updated code.